# inverse continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I cant find the 
inverse function to
$$f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x(x-1)²}-1 $$
on the interval $[-1, +\infty[$

Comment: The inverse satisfies the equation $x=f(f^{-1}(x))=\sqrt[3]{f^{-1}(x)(f^{-1}(x)-1)^2}-1$. Therefore, $f^{-1}(x)(f^{-1}(x)-1)^2=(x+1)^3$. From this you can solve for $f^{-1}(x)$ using [these formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#General_cubic_formula).

Comment: thank you very much for the help

Comment: If this is not the original problem, take into account that many properties of the inverse function can be determined without computing it.

Comment: can this inverse function be determined without  the conditionalmethose ?